# How to get CPE from package?

Tags: security, nist

I have a question related to CPE. Does it exist a method that ensure full translation among package installed and its CPE?
Example: package for apache2, in Ubuntu or RedHat, is named apache2 or httpd but its CPE is similar to :apache:http_server: (apache is the vendor and http_server the product name) and obviously if I search for CPE like ::apache2: or ::httpd: I cannot found nothing.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the registered products in the CPE database on https://nvd.nist.gov/products/cpe

Some distributions add CPE information also in the packages, so you can use the package manager to look it up.
Gentoo Linux for instance provides a `cpe` field in the [metadata.xml file](https://devmanual.gentoo.org/ebuild-writing/misc-files/metadata/index.html).

Additionally you can look up the [CPE data in repology](https://repology.org/security/recent-cpes) which is not authoritative.